# Compute conditional probability $P(x\geq \frac 12 \mid y=2x)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Consider the PDF $$f(x,y)=\frac 12 xy\quad\text{if}\quad 0\leq x\leq y\leq2,\qquad f(x,y)=0\quad \text{otherwise}$$
>   How to compute
>   $$P\left(\left.x\geq \frac 12 \right| y=2x\right)\ ?$$

I can solve $P(x \in A | y \in B )$  when $A$ and $B$ are intervals
but this conditioning uses $y=2x$, which is a line.

How to control $x$ and $y$ ?

Comment: By your notation, do you mean $f$ is the joint density of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ and that you are to find $P(X\geq 1/2 \mid Y = 2X)$?

Comment: yes , I did it a few minute ago . by transformation of variable but I want the other method

Comment: Tell me, were you asked to solve this in the setting of some university lectures? If yes, can you make precise what these are? The reason I am asking you this is that questions based on the fallacy I explained in my answer pop up regularly on the site, hence I am curious to understand if some curricula are flawed or what...

Comment: @Did I'm just a university math student, I was received that question from my friend, and I don't know if the question of which books.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two natural interpretations of the question, which lead to different solutions and show the question is not well founded.

---

First, $Y=2X$ means that $Z=2$ with $Z=Y/X$ hence this could be asking for $u(2)$, where $$P(X\geqslant \tfrac12\mid Z)=u(Z)$$
To compute this, note that the joint PDF of $(X,Z)$ is $$f_{X,Z}(x,z)=\tfrac12x^3z\quad\text{on}\quad x>0,\ z>1,\ x<\tfrac2z$$
hence, for every $z>1$, the conditional PDF is $$f_{X\mid Z}(x\mid z)\propto  x^3\quad\text{on}\quad 0<x<\tfrac2z$$ that is,
$$f_{X\mid Z}(x\mid z)=\tfrac14z^4x^3\quad\text{on}\quad 0<x<\tfrac2z$$
In particular, $$f_{X\mid Z}(x\mid 2)=4x^3\quad\text{on}\quad 0<x<1$$ hence 
$$P(X\geqslant \tfrac12\mid Z=2)=\int_{1/2}^14x^3dx=1-\tfrac1{16}$$

---

But $Y=2X$ also means that $T=0$ with $T=Y-2X$ hence this could as well be asking for $v(0)$, where
$$P(X\geqslant \tfrac12\mid T)=v(T)$$
To compute this, note that the joint PDF of $(X,T)$ is $$f_{X,T}(x,t)=\tfrac12x(t+2x)\quad\text{on}\quad 0<x<t+2x<2$$
hence, for every $|t|<2$, the conditional PDF is $$f_{X\mid T}(x\mid t)\propto  x(t+2x)\quad\text{on}\quad x>0,\ x>-t,\ x<1-t/2$$
In particular, $$f_{X\mid T}(x\mid 0)=3x^2\quad\text{on}\quad 0<x<1$$
hence $$P(X\geqslant \tfrac12\mid T=0)=\int_{1/2}^13x^2dx=1-\tfrac18$$

---

Hmmm... $1-\tfrac1{16}\ne1-\tfrac1{8}$, right? So, which solution is correct? Both are, and perhaps yet a third one...

Comment: yes i did below solution 7/8 is answer!

Comment: If you mean "an answer", then you are right. If you mean "the answer", then you are wrong.

Comment: what's mean? i can't english well  . answer is 7/8 correct

Comment: Yeah, the answer 7/8 is correct, as I show above, **and** the answer 15/16 is also correct, as I show above, **and** other answers might be correct as well.

Comment: i dont understand that answer is various could tell me that? Something more condition?

Comment: I learned something new (+1).

Comment: @cossi Sorry but did you try to read my answer? Your comments sound as if you did not even read one line from it...

Comment: Oh I see thanks !  i feel so strange .. it's over my knowledge

Comment: @Did How did you come up with the conditional distribution for $X|Z$ ? I ask this because it doesn't work for all values of $z$. For instance, take $z=4$, $f_{X\mid Z}(x\mid 4)=2^{-2}x^3$. Integrating that function over the domain $0<x<1/2$, we get $2^{-8}$, not $1$.

Comment: @user97890 Right, the correct formula is $f_{X\mid Z}(x\mid z)=\tfrac14z^4x^3$ on $0<x<\tfrac2z$, for every $z>1$, thanks for signalling it.

Comment: @Did When calculating the new joint distribution for $(X,Z)$ from $(X,Y)$, keeping the integral expression invariant: $\int_0^2 \int_x^2 \frac{1}{2}xydydx = 1$, noting that $y = xz \Rightarrow dy = xdz + zdx$ and substituting for limits, we get $\int_0^2 \int_1^{2/x} \left(\frac{1}{2}x^3zdzdx + \frac{1}{2}x^2z^2(dx)^2\right) = 1$. Even though the second term doesn't make any sense, is it really okay to simply throw it away? I feel like something fundamentally changes in this mapping. Can you shed more light on why this is valid?

Comment: @user97890 This has little to do with the question and more with basic changes of variables in multiple integrals. You might wish to look for he Jacobian version, which amounts to say that $(dx)^2=0$, yes.

Comment: @Did Thanks for that. Is there any insight into _why_ this problem has multiple solutions? And any practical implications it might have? I just can't seem to wrap my head around a probabilistic event having 2 different probability of occurrence.

Comment: "a probabilistic event having 2 different probability of occurrence" Hugh. This is not at all what my answer shows.

Comment: @Did But you mentioned both solutions are correct!

Comment: @user97890 Yeah, both are correct and each corresponds to a specific interpretation of an otherwise undefined notation. Take-home message: the expression $P(X\geqslant\frac12\mid Y=2X)$ is ill-formed.