# Joint distribution conditioned on a path

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $A \sim EXP(\alpha)$ and $B \sim EXP(\beta)$ be two independent random variables. Then their joint distribution is given by:

$$
f_{A,B}(a, b) = f_A(a) \times f_B(b) = \alpha \beta e^{-\alpha a - \beta b}
$$

I want to compute $\Pr(A > a ~|~ B = kA)$ where $k>0$ is some constant (sort of like the survival function conditioned on a straight line). My gut tells me to follow these steps:

$$
\Pr(A>a ~|~ B=kA)
           = \frac{\int_a^\infty f_{A,B}(a, ka) da}{\int_0^\infty f_{A,B}(a, ka) da} \\
\hspace{23mm}    = e^{-(\alpha + k\beta) a}
$$

1. Is the solution correct? Is there another method for solving this?
2. Why can't we invoke the rule of independence and claim $\Pr(A>a ~|~ B=kA) = \Pr(A>a)$ since $A$ and $B$ are independent?
3. Which resource would you recommend for an in-depth understanding of this topic? *Introduction to Mathematical Statistics* by *Hogg and Craig*?

Comment: The question is ill posed, see [this recent post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2184861/6179) for in-depth explanations.

Comment: @Did I see... From what I understand, this problem is ill-formed, right? So is there a way to add constraints to it to make it well-formed? (Also, I did not understand how you calculated the pdf of (X, Z) and (X, T), where can I read more about that?)

Comment: I meant to say *ill-formed = not well-founded, and *well-formed = well-founded...

Comment: What is your source for this exercise?

Comment: @Did This was not an exercise. I am trying to model a system's behavior as part of a project (at my university). But having only little background in statistics, I find myself unable find a consistent solution to the problem.

Comment: @Did It would be great if you could suggest a resource for learning all this. Is the book by Hogg the best one in your opinion?